# No such file or directory error while execute commands from script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working on a script that takes commands from MySQL and executes them one by one. My problem is I can't execute the commands from script:

> ./bash.sh: line 26: /myscript.sh -c "":  no such file or directory

Line 26 is the command I wish to execute ("$com"). if i try to run the command manually, by echoing the content of "$com" and than run it from terminal, it's working.

What am I doing wrong?

```
if [ ! "${#array[*]}" -eq "0" ]; then
for (( i=0 ; i<cnt ; i++ )); do
        id=$(echo "${array[$i]}" | sed 's@\t@^@g' | cut -f'1' -d'^')
        com=$(echo "${array[$i]}" | sed 's@\t@^@g' | cut -f'2' -d'^')
        imp=$(echo "${array[$i]}" | sed 's@\t@^@g' | cut -f'3' -d'^')

        if [[ "$id" = [0-9]* ]]; then
                "$com"
                echo "DELETE FROM list WHERE id='$id'" | mysql "$DB_USER" -u "$DB_USER" -p"$DB_PASS"
        fi
done
else
        echo "The list is empty"
fi
```

Comment: @Vaughn Cato it worked like a charm!

Comment: echo ${array[$i]} and see what the value is just above the "com" line maybe there is no field 2 when you are doing cut ...this might help you debug it better.

Comment: It is difficult understand what you are trying to do, but you should probably read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050. It explains why you should not store commands in variables, and what can be done instead

Comment: The real issue is how you populate `array` in the first place.  Consider maintaining a collection of parallel arrays, i.e. `cmd[$i]` would contain the command to execute, `id[$i]` the ID, `imp[$i]` the value for `imp`.

Answer (score 4):

**Added as Community Wiki**

This question was solved in the comments by *Vaughn Cato* and the OP hasn't been seen since March.

The accept answer there was to use `eval` so the if statement in the script would be:

```
if [[ "$id" = [0-9]* ]]; then
   eval "$com"
   echo "DELETE FROM list WHERE id='$id'" | mysql "$DB_USER" -u "$DB_USER" -p"$DB_PASS"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
"$com"
```

rather to

```
$com
```

(remember: too many quotes can be as harmful as too few)

than to

```
eval "$com"
```

- it is unnecessarily complicated to use `eval` just to undo the unwanted effect of quoting.